# The FilePath is correct but it says "Cannot GET /Login/SignUp/signup.html"

Tags: html

[Here's what the code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfOhq.png)

As you can see the path is correct and last time everything is working fine until I put them on separated folders to be more organized, when I go to the href of the file it always starts as "/Login/SignUp/signup.html" even though I did not put the Login in the path on the href. btw everything is like this now and every file can't be find, should I just remove them from individual folders or is there better solution?

I was expecting it to go from Login into SignUp

Comment: btw I tried putting the whole path in the html, still didn't work it always starts with login for some reason

Answer (score 0):

In the `<a>` tag try using `href="../SignUp/signup.html"`

- `../` is used to go up one level in the folder hierarchy.

Comment: This answer is at least partially incorrect. backslashes are [never used to delimit directories in hyperlinks](https://www.teamits.com/connection/qa/slashes.html)

Comment: this is all on sql localhost